# Impossible to login with new civicrm user

Tags: drupal, contacts, user

I have created a Drupal 7 website with civicrm . My problem is when I create an account with Drupal and I would like to reset password I don't have problem's. The account is automatically created in civiCRM .
But when I create a contact in civiCRM, an user is created in Drupal 7 . When I would like to reinitialize this user password, the process don't have problem's.

But when I would like to log out and login with new password, I can't.

I have checked in drupal's table "user" .

They don't have difference between drupal user created and civicrm user created. The permissions are same and the generated passwords are ok and the cache cleaned.

Any person have any idea ? I use Drupal 7.43 and 4.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have found my problem's solution. The cause was the user generated by civicrm had a username that wasn't the e-mail. I trying to login using the e-mail not the username. I have install this module and now they works .

https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration

Comment: if you are saying that creating a User from the civicrm contact record results in the user not having the same email as the civicrm contact then that sounds like a real problem. but i don't quite follow your question.

Comment: thx for helping clarify that joanne